# Android : Activity and Service communication

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I have on Service that must communicate with an Activity (MyActivity) through a BradcastReceiver. This BroadcastReceiver is declare intosame activity so :

```
    private class MessaggiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public static final String ACTION_RELOAD = "it.android.dev.thecode.ACTION_RELOAD";
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_RELOAD)){
                leggi_act; //Method of MyActivity
            }
        }

    }
```

but how must declare into Manifest the brodcast contained within the MyActivity ? I used this code with it.android.dev.thecode.MyActivity.MessaggiReceiver

```
<receiver android:name="it.android.dev.thecode.MyActivity.MessaggiReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="it.android.dev.thecode.ACTION_RELOAD"></action>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

but is wrong then I used this code with it.android.dev.thecode.myactivity$MessaggiReceiver

```
<receiver android:name="it.android.dev.thecode.MyActivity$MessaggiReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="it.android.dev.thecode.ACTION_RELOAD"></action>
                </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Thanks

Comment: if you declare it in the manifest, then the class that implements it must be visible i.e. not `private`. Put it in a separate file and make the class `public`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to register a broadcast receiver in your manifest, instead register it by code in your activity's onResume. Don't forget to unregister in onPause to avoid any leaks.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
   registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
       new IntentFilter("it.android.dev.thecode.ACTION_RELOAD"));
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
   unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
}

private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("receiver", "Got broadcast: " + intent.getAction());
  }
};
```

Comment: My Broadcast must always work than I don't insert unregisterReceiver code into onPause ?

Comment: When you dont have your activity visible, then of course it should not listen for any broadcasts too, that's how it should suppose to work. If you don't unregister your broadcast in onPause, the framework will throw warnings in logcat and will forcefully drop its listening. So its better to be nice in advance with the activity life-cycle by unregistering in onPause